# Can I clean electric wall heaters with soap and water?

Tags: electrical, hvac, water, electric-heat

I bought some TPI Electric Wall Heaters. The product is starting to whistle a little bit after 5 years. I purchased an electronic canned air blower, and blew out all the dust in there, including the fans. It helped somewhat.

Someone mentioned instead of cleaning using an air can, I should also clean blades lightly with moist soap and water. I'm thinking most of the dust seems to be gone from the blades with the canned air.

1. Would cleaning the blades with moist water really help sound reduce dramatically? (after I already cleaned with an air duster) Just asking before I go to the 6 heaters in my house.
2. Any other suggestions to clean also?

[TPI Wall Heater Specs](http://productsearch.tpicorp.com/heating/wall-heaters/4300/4300-series-low-profile-fan-forced-wall-heater-with-wall-box-double-pole-thermostat/-/standard-models)

[image: electric wall heater]

Comment: The noise could also be the fan bearings wearing out after 6 years.

Comment: How easy is it to take each one of those outdoors for a *proper* blow-through? A can of compressed air is really nowhere near powerful enough to do a proper cleaning job. You want one of these - https://www.amazon.co.uk/XPOWER-Electric-Computer-Duster-Vacuums/dp/B082XZDJ2D You really need to do this outdoors, or be prepared to have to Hoover the entire house, three times ;) I have that specific make, bought to do the computers. It looks a bit cheap in the photos, but it packs one heck of a punch. [Don't touch any fan with the nozzle as they're spinning, unless you want to pick all the bits up]

Answer (score 1):

Some dirt/dust might be caked on and air alone might not be enough.

Turn off the breaker/s first and use the least amount of water, just damp rags/sponges.

Make sure they are perfectly dry before turning the breakers back on.

Comment: are you saying even a thin amount of barely visible dust on the fans can make it whistle? interesting

Comment: Most rotating objects should be balanced.  Unless the added dirt/dust keeps the blades in balance, then you get reduced efficiently and if unbalanced enough then extra noise.  The unbalanced weight can also damage/wear out bearings in time.  Just think what a small chicken/bird does to a big jet engine.  Not good for the engine or the chicken.  Have you taken the cover off yet and checked?

Comment: ok I'll do it anyway, although I don't even see enough dust weight to have a balancing issue, thanks , the dust is very minimal

Comment: @mattsmith5  A whistle/whine sound might also be a bearing going bad/needing oil/grease.  I would not really expect this just after five years, but a lot of quality has gone down.  If they are all producing the noise instead of just one or two, I would be concerned of the quality of their products.